# Why bool func of HasFlag analog ((data & flag) == flag) always return true

Tags: unity-game-engine, compute-shader

I am having a problem checking for flags. For some reason it always returns True. (The same function works correctly on the CPU.)

```
bool HasFlag(uint data, uint flag) { return (data & flag) == flag; }
```

Check:

```
if (HasFlag(tag, Invisible | Deleted))
```

When writing a check without a function, everything is considered correct:

```
if (tag & (Invisible | Deleted) == (Invisble | Deleted))
```

Full code:

```
const uint Invisible = 1 << 0;
const uint Deleted = 1 << 1;
const uint Selected = 1 << 2;

struct Tag
{
    uint tag;
};

RWStructuredBuffer<uint> IndexBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<float3> PositionBuffer;
StructuredBuffer<float> ScaleBuffer;
RWStructuredBuffer<Tag> TagsBuffer;
AppendStructuredBuffer<uint> SelectedItems;
AppendStructuredBuffer<uint> SelectedIndex;
int Length;

float3 RayOrigin;
float3 RayDirection;
float ScaleFactor;

uint SetFlag(uint data, uint flag) { return data | flag; }
uint UnsetFlag(uint data, uint flag) { return data & (~flag); }
uint FlipFlag(uint data, uint flag) { return data ^ flag; }
bool HasFlag(uint data, uint flag) { return (data & flag) == flag; } //<-- problem func

#pragma kernel PointSelect
[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void PointSelect(uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    if (id.x < Length)
    {
        uint tag = TagsBuffer[id.x].tag;

        if (HasFlag(tag, Invisible | Deleted)) //<--- always passes (tag == 0)
        {
            float3 pos = PositionBuffer[id.x];
            float3 spos = pos - RayOrigin;
            float scale = ScaleBuffer[id.x] * 0.2f * ScaleFactor;

            float dist = sqrt(spos.x*spos.x + spos.y*spos.y + spos.z*spos.z);
            float3 rayPos = RayOrigin + dist*RayDirection;
            float3 srPos = rayPos - pos;

            if (srPos.x*srPos.x + srPos.y*srPos.y + srPos.z*srPos.z <= scale * scale)
            {
                TagsBuffer[id.x].tag = tag | Selected;
                SelectedItems.Append(IndexBuffer[id.x]);
                SelectedIndex.Append(id.x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance.
P.S. Google Translate

Edit 1: I noticed that in my example, differently arranged brackets and decided to check the priority of operators (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). As a result, == takes precedence over &. As a result, the "correctly executed variant" looks like: `date & (flag == flag)`. Why it works - I can't imagine. I'll go figure it out.

Edit 2: These funcs work correctly on CPU, but on GPU always return true for some unknown reason:

```
inline bool AllFlags(uint data, uint flags) { return (data & flags) == flags; }
inline bool AnyFlags(uint data, uint flags) { return (data & flags) > 0; }
inline bool NoneFlags(uint data, uint flags) { return (data & flags) == 0; }
```

Edit 3: When I use numbers instead of constants when calling functions everything works. The error lies in the definition of constants.

Answer (score 0):

As I was able to understand, the problem was hidden in the fact that when declaring constants I did not register that they are static. As a result, as I understand it, they took the value 0 regardless of what value I assigned them.
The problem was solved when changing:

```
const uint Invisible = 1 << 0;
const uint Deleted = 1 << 1;
const uint Selected = 1 << 2;
```

On the:

```
static const uint Invisible = 1 << 0;
static const uint Deleted = 1 << 1;
static const uint Selected = 1 << 2;
```

I hope no one else will step on my rake. A lot of hours went down the drain because of the most banal thing.